# Compatible versions between spring and elasticsearch

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, elasticsearch, version

**what are the compatible versions between spring and elasticsearch in 2020???**

Comment: See https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#preface.requirements

Comment: you can use it to use the es7.x https://github.com/zt9788/easy.framework.elasticsearch